# EE 6 Upgrade: System folder path not set correctly

Tags: upgrade

I went through the upgrade from the latest previous version to EE6 using the automated button.

Everything came back green, except I'm now getting this error message:

```
Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

My system folder is just "system" and both files appear to be set correctly.  The only thing I can think of is that I had a soft-link to "backend", and when I did the upgrade, I was at "https://www.website.com/backend".  I had never considered this an issue or possible item before.

(Renaming "system" to "backend" and updating the two php files does *not* resolve, unfortunately...)

Any help is greatly appreciated.  :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually download and unzip the EE6 release. Then copy over the index.php and admin.php files and also the system/index.php file.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so very much.  :-)